# Qt Creator: add custom build configuration settings in .pro

Tags: c++, qt, build, qt-creator

I am trying to add build settings for a custom build configuration.

By default Qt Creator creates `debug` and `release` configurations (http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtcreator-2.4/creator-build-settings.html).

For those configs you can add custom build settings. For ex:

```
release: DESTDIR = $${build_root_dir}/release
debug:   DESTDIR = $${build_root_dir}/debug
```

I created another build configuration called `debug_menu_active` in Qt Creator.
And I'd like to use the same kind of statements:

```
debug_menu_active: DEFINES += FORCE_ACTIVE_MENU_DEBUG
debug_menu_active: DESTDIR = $${build_root_dir}/debug_menu_active
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work `message("DEFINES: "$${DEFINES})` gives:

```
Project MESSAGE: DEFINES :UNICODE QT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT
```

I think I need to define something else, but I have no clue what it could be.

Could someone help me with this?

Thanks!

## Update:

I tested @svlasov answer, but unfortunately it breaks the compilation:

```
qtinternal\moc\moc_scenario.cpp:10:154: error: scenario.h: No such file or directory
qtinternal\moc\moc_scenario.cpp:12:2: error: #error "The header file 'scenario.h' doesn't include <QObject>."
qtinternal\moc\moc_scenario.cpp:20: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before 'static'
qtinternal\moc\moc_scenario.cpp:48: error: 'scenario' has not been declared
qtinternal\moc\moc_scenario.cpp:48: error: variable or field 'qt_static_metacall' declared void
qtinternal\moc\moc_scenario.cpp:48: error: 'QObject' was not declared in this scope
qtinternal\moc\moc_scenario.cpp:48: error: '_o' was not declared in this scope
qtinternal\moc\moc_scenario.cpp:48: error: 'QMetaObject' has not been declared
qtinternal\moc\moc_scenario.cpp:48: error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
qtinternal\moc\moc_scenario.cpp:48: error: expected primary-expression before 'void'
```

Here is how I did it:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under `Build Steps`, for `qmake` step set `Additional arguments` as:

```
CONFIG+=debug_menu_active
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My custom define is now properly added in DEFINES, but now the compilation is broken. I update my answer with the results of your solution. Do you have any idea?

Comment: So it doesn't brake otherwise? Try to wrap the argument into quotes `"CONFIG+=..."`

Comment: No it doesn't break in debug (for ex.) if add the DEFINE that I need. To rephrase that: I can launch my app with debug configuration in which I add the DEFINE.

Comment: I just tried and I still get the same error. But it seems this is something else related to the config selection. Since my question was 'how to add a DEFINE for a given custom config' and that this part is working, I am going to accept your answer. I'll open a new one later :). Thank you again!